# How can I set memory capacity of each TIKV?

Tags: tidb, tikv

How can I set the capacity of a TIKV instance? Lets say I have 2 TIKV instances and I want them to consume 200GB of storage (each 100GB).

Answer (score 0):

TiKV checks the amount of free disk space to determine the storage capacity. If needed you can use the [`--capacity`](https://docs.pingcap.com/tidb/stable/command-line-flags-for-tikv-configuration#--capacity) commandline flag to set a different capacity if needed.